# CRichEditCtrl: Cannot replace selection with Unicode string

Tags: c++, mfc, cricheditctrl

In MFC/C++, I have a rich edit 2.0 control, class `CRichEditCtrl`, which is `RichEdit20W`. Rich edit 2.0 controls are supposed to support Unicode. I am using it to display Unicode characters. But the `ReplaceSel` function doesn't accept Unicode strings. For example

```
CRichEditCtrl re;
wstring line;
auto x = line.c_str(); // array of const wchar_t
re.ReplaceSel(x); // ERROR
```

gets a compiler error because `CRichEditCtrl::ReplaceSel` is prototyped as

```
void ReplaceSel(LPCTSTR lpszNewText, BOOL bCanUndo = FALSE);
```

and `LPCTSTR` is a `const char *`.

How can I replace using a Unicode string?

Windows 11 Pro  Visual Studio 2022

Answer (score 5):

If `LPCTSTR` is `const char *` then your project settings are multibyte characters and not unicode. The answer is simple, you have to convert the unicode string to ansi, using your preferred conversion function, eg `WidecharToMultibyte()`, `wcstombs()` or `std::codecvt`. Please note that you are converting the string to a type capable of representing **fewer** character values, ie these functions may fail.

---

**EDIT:**
You can call the `IsWindowUnicode()` function to check if the control is indeed unicode. And you can experiment further with the `WM_SETTEXT` message for example (not the `SetWindowText()` function) to find out with more certainty (ie if it works with ansi or wide strings). If your project setting is multibyte chars (ie the `UNICODE` identifier is not defined), then `CEdit::ReplaceSel()` takes an ansi string (as the function uses the dual/conditional `T` notation, which translates to either `W` or `A`, depending on `UNICODE` being defined/undefined), even if the underlying control is actually Unicode. This is a discrepancy of course, arising from the fact that MFC assumes that all its controls are ansi or unicode, consistent with the project setting. In this case I would try sending the `EM_REPLACESEL` message directly, (of which `CEdit::ReplaceSel()` is a wrapper), (ie `re.SendMessage(EM_REPLACESEL, bCanUndo, (LPARAM)x)`), or even calling `ReplaceSel()` with the string type cast (ie `re.ReplaceSel((LPCTSTR)x)`); although this may seem wrong it's actually not, as the cast won't perform any conversion, it will just keep the compiler from complaining and will pass the wide string address to the function (and finally the message), which is correct, assuming a Unicode underlying control.

Comment: My project setting is "Not set", because almost all of the code is ANSI (char). This one control is an exception. I changed it from `RICHEDIT20A` to `RICHEDIT20W` in the resource file.

Comment: @Woody20 His answer is correct. The MFC framework will accept strings based on the project settings. Set them to Unicode and job done.

Comment: @Constantine Georgiou: I used `IsWindowUnicode(re.m_hWnd);` it returns false. So that explains the behavior. I need to somehow tell the compiler the control is to be Unicode, and I'm not sure how to so so.

Comment: @Andrew Truckle: Unfortunately, making the entire project Unicode is not an option. It's hundreds of source files, and its data is stored as ANSI text. If I knew where the compiler tests the preprocessor variable `_UNICODE` maybe I could trick it for just this control.

Comment: You can try sending the `CCM_SETUNICODEFORMAT` message (with a `wParam` of 1) during initialization (`OnInitDialog()` for dialogs, `OnInitialUpdate()` for views), but I believe this won't work. Otherwise, you have to find out who's the culprit (you set a unicode class name in the resource but get an ansi control), it can be Win32 or MFC. In MFC you may be able to change its behaviour if you subclass the control (define and use a new class for the control, overriding members like `PreCreateWindow()`, `PreSubclassWindow()`, `Create()` etc) - you have to dig deep into the MFC sources for this.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou: Thanks for your useful suggestions. As you suspected, `CCM_SETUNICODEFORMAT` didn't work. `PreCreateWindow` does nothing for a rich edit control, `PreSubClassWindow` cannot change to Unicode. The choice between ANSI and Unicode occurs in one of the header files as a preprocessor variable. I did, however, solve my problem; see my next post.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to use a Unicode rich text control in an ANSI project.

First, I created a new Win32 (not MFC) project, with the character set set to Unicode. The type of project was static library. This project contained only the following code:

```
#include "framework.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "RichEdit.h"

HWND CreateRichEdit(HWND hwndOwner,        // Dialog box handle.
    int x, int y,          // Location.
    int width, int height, // Dimensions.
    HINSTANCE hinst)       // Application or DLL instance.
{
    LoadLibrary(TEXT("Msftedit.dll"));

    HWND hwndEdit = CreateWindowEx(0, MSFTEDIT_CLASS, TEXT("Type here"),
        ES_MULTILINE | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP,
        x, y, width, height,
        hwndOwner, NULL, hinst, NULL);

    return hwndEdit;
}
```

I then used the `CreateRichEdit` function in my "real", not Unicode, project, by linking my project with the static library. Using the window handle output by `CreateRichEdit`, I could send Unicode text to the rich edit control, using edit messages.

Here is an example function which adds a line of Unicode text to the rich edit control:

```
void AddLine(HWND h, wstring &line)
{
    line += L"\n";
    GETTEXTLENGTHEX g; g.flags = GTL_DEFAULT; g.codepage = 1200; // Unicode
    size_t nBegin = ::SendMessageW(h, EM_GETTEXTLENGTHEX, (WPARAM)&g, 0);
    CHARRANGE r; r.cpMin = r.cpMax = (long)nBegin;
    auto what1 = ::SendMessageW(h, EM_EXSETSEL, (WPARAM)&r, 0);
    SETTEXTEX s; s.flags = ST_DEFAULT; s.codepage = 1200;
    auto ok = ::SendMessageW(h, EM_SETTEXTEX, (WPARAM)&r, (LPARAM)line.data()); // Combines the functionality of the WM_SETTEXT and EM_REPLACESEL
    return;
}
```

The last trick is that you need to use `line.data()`, not `line`, `&line`, or `line.c_str()` in the `EM_SETTEXTEX` message.